# How to use authenticate method with AbstractUser model django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I`m wrirting site on Django and I need to make a system for registration and authorization of work peepers, for this I use the Django AbstractUser model, registration works well, but authorization does not work, and the authenticate method returns None

Here is my JobseekerRegsiterInfo model:

```
class JobseekerRegisterInfo(AbstractUser):
    username = first_name = last_name = None
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone_number', 'full_name', 'hashed_password']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

My login form:

```
class JobseekerLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Введіть ваш Email: ',
                             widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label='Ваш пароль: ',
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        # if not select_field_value_from_model(JobseekerRegisterInfo, 'email', email):
        if not JobseekerRegisterInfo.objects.filter(email=email):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Неправильно введені email або пароль')
        return email
```

and view function:

```
def jobseeker_login_view(request):
    title = 'Авторизація'
    context = {'title': title}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JobseekerLoginForm(request.POST)
        context['form'] = form
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
            print(generate_password_hash(password))
            if user:
                print(user)
            else:
                print('USER IS NONE')
        else:
            form_errors = form.errors.as_data()
            custom_error = custom_error_service(form_errors)
            context['list_first_error'] = custom_error
    else:
        form = JobseekerLoginForm()
        context['form'] = form
    return render(request, template_name='jobseeker/jobseeker_login.html', context=context)
```

But only USER IS NONE is displayed in the console, no matter what I do

Tell me, please, how to use authenticate correctly in my case

Comment: Do you see any form errors? Also, aren't you supposed to pass `username` kwarg to `authenticate` method, not `email`?

Comment: I also don't see errors in the form, but about the username field, I decided that my model would not have this field, so I specified USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

Comment: You need to have an authentication backend whose `authenticate` method can receive the `email` kwarg. The default backend takes username and password.

Comment: How can I create this authenctication backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic Difference between `AbstractUser` and `AbstractBaseUser`

### AbstractUser

AbstractUser class inherits the User class and is used to add Additional Fields required for your User in Database itself. SO its change the schema of the database. It is basically used to add fields like date_of_birth , location and bio etc. to the existing User model This is Done to the very Beginning of the project. which means you will get the complete field which by default come with the user Model plus the following field that you add/define.

[image]

### AbstractBaseUser

AbstractBaseUser has the authentication functionality only , it has no actual fields you will supply the fields to use when you subclass.

you have to till that what fields represent username fields, and how those users will be managed

for example, you have to use email in your authentication, Normally Django uses a username in authentication, so how do you change it to use email?

[image]

## NOTE - So, You need to Inherit `AbstractBaseUser` instead of `AbstractUser` to use Django's built-in authentication functionality.